# Bitwise Clarification

Tags: php, mysql, bit-manipulation

First and foremost, please let me clarify that I'm not a native english speaker, so please, excuse me for my faults.

I'm currently creating a PHP user system using a bitwise system permissions, and I will be stocking theses permissions into a MySQL database.

My question is the following. 
What type of row (int, varchar, ...) should I use to stock the permissions

My second question would be, how many permissions can be stocked? (32 bits have a limit of ~32 permissions (I think))

Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use one of the [integer types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html). Which one depends on how many permissions you'll require.

`TINYINT` will allow for `8` permissions

`SMALLINT` will allow for `16` permissions

`MEDIUMINT` will allow for `24` permissions

`INT` will allow for `32` permissions

`BIGINT` will allow for `64` permissions

Comment: Yeah, that is what I decided to do... 5 months ago -.-

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [BIT(1)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html) data type. Then you can use a `bit` column for every permission seperatly.

Comment: Would be pretty hard to do bitwise operation if everything has a bit set to 0 or 1